# How register gitlab ci runner on rancher2(kubernetes) without install gitlab-ci-multi-runner package?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, rancher, kubernetes-helm

Run rancher version of 2.
Run kubernetes on 3 node.
Add key and value at ConfigMap in Rancher

```
name = "Kubernetes Runner"
url = "https://url/ci"
token = "TOKEN"
executor = "kubernetes"
[runners.kubernetes]
```

Try run and register gitlab ci runner on rancher2(kubernetes).:
Created Deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: gitlab
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: gitlab-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: gitlab-runner
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - run
        image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: gitlab-runner
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/gitlab-runner
          name: config
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: gitlab-runner
        name: config
```

After build get error:

```
Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory builds=0.
```

Try install custom helm catalog at rancher, but i dont found how do it using gui.
helm commad not found on rancher server and kubernetes node.

How register gitlab ci runner on rancher2(kubernetes) without install gitlab-ci-multi-runner package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your ConfigMap was not created correctly.

You can try this:

```bash
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner
  namespace: gitlab
data:
  config.toml: |
    concurrent = 10

    [[runners]]
      name = "Kubernetes Runner"
      url = "https://gitlab.com/"
      token = "xxxxxx"
      executor = "kubernetes"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "gitlab"
        image = "debian:9"
        privileged = true
```

Save the content to `config.yaml` file, then use `kubeclt apply -f config.yaml` to create it.